# Как реализовать цикл нахождения простых чисел?

Tags: c++, циклы

> Даны N положительных целых чисел, которые не делятся ни на какие
> простые числа, кроме 2 и 3. Удалить из массива числа так, чтобы из
> любых двух оставшихся одно число делилось на другое.

Думал над тем, как реализовать цикл нахождения простых чисел.

Насчет массивов, я знаю что можно было использовать динамический массив, просто в университете требуют использовать пока этот метод, до тех пор, пока мы до них(динамических массивов) не дойдем.

Вот так пробовал реализовать(хотел найти сначала все простые числа от 4 до текущего числа, потом сделать проверку чтобы из всех простых чисел данное число делилось только на 2 и 3):

```
        srand((unsigned)time(0));
        const int maxLength = 100;

        int array[maxLength] = { 0 };
        int a_length = 101;

        while (a_length > maxLength)
        {
            std::cout << "Enter the length of array (less than 100): ";
            std::cin >> a_length;
        }

        int number = 0;
        int simple_numbers[maxLength];
        int simple_length = 0;
        int marker_simple = 0;
        int marker_number = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a_length; i++)
a:      {
            number = rand() % 101;
            if (number % 2 == 0 && number % 3 == 0 && number != 0)
            {
                // find all simple numbers from j to number
                for (int j = 4; j < number; j++)
                {
                    int k;
                    for (k = 2; k < j; k++)
                        if (j % k == 0)
                        {
                            j++;
                            k = 2;
                            marker_simple = 0;
                        }
                        else
                            marker_simple++;
                    if (marker_simple != j - k)
                    {
                        simple_length++;
                        simple_numbers[simple_length - 1] = j;
                    }
                }

                //check: if number devide to anyone 
                //simple number besides the 2 and 3 than change the number
                int z;
                for (z = 0; z < simple_length; z++)
                {
                    if (number % simple_numbers[z] == 0)
                        goto a;
                    else
                        marker_number++;
                }
                if (marker_number != simple_length - z)
                    array[i] = number;
            }
            else
            {
                i--;
                continue;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Вроде Вы не совсем  верно поняли задачу - в массив уже только числа вида `2^p*3^q`

Comment: Нет , это я понял, просто интерестно было как реализовать чтобы программа сама искала эти числа. Подправил неманого описание проблемы.

Comment: Для проверки, что число именно такого вида, не нужно искать простые. Делить на 2, пока делится. Потом делить на 3, пока делится. Получилась единица - успех.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверка на то, что число вида `2^p*3^q` (например - 12,27,72,64):

```
while (n%2==0)
   n/=2;
while (n%3==0)
   n/=3;
if (n==1) - ДА!
```

Задача в целом же не полностью определена - если достаточно найти любое подмножество - просто ищем пару чисел, одно из которых делится на другое.

Если же нужно найти максимальное подмножество - это выглядит как `задача о максимальной клике на графе`, и сложновато для текущего учебного уровня (например, можно использовать алгоритм Брона-Кербоша)

Comment: Пару можно не искать. Пустое множество решает задачу.

Comment: Поиск максимального подмножества для степеней двух простых делается динамикой по парам целых чисел - показателей степеней.